# When I Download My Android App, The Name Is Different

Tags: android

I published only 3 apps on android so far. In this app, I named it "Home Point System" before publishing. And I can see it on PlayStore with that name. But when I download it on my device i see it's name as com.name.package's "Package" on my device's menu. How can i fix this?

Comment: post your manifest. especially the main activity declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Name in the device's menu is taken from manifest.xml not from PlayStore

```
<application
    android:name="com.name.package"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="Home Point System"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Change android:label with the name of your app